# Xamarin Forms: To have controls overlapped on top of map

Tags: android, google-maps, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have some controls such as images and also text box which I wish to be overlapped on top of my map control. The text box acts as a search text box should appear at the top and the images should appear at the bottom left.

How can I accomplish this in the simplest way using Xamarin Forms?

Appreciate if someone could provide sample code.

Answer (score 3):

It's not as hard as you might think. Just use a `Grid` or similar and place controls in the same column or row to have them overlap.

You probably want the map control to span the whole `Grid` and then have some rows/columns in place for the places where you want to have the other controls.

For instance, have a look at this example by Kym Phillpotts: https://github.com/kphillpotts/XamarinFormsLayoutChallenges/blob/master/GreatPlaces/GreatPlaces/GreatPlaces/MainPage.xaml

The notable code is inside the `ViewCell`:

```
<Grid RowSpacing="5" ColumnSpacing="0" Margin="10,5" >
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Image Source="{Binding HeroImage}" Aspect="AspectFill" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
<Image Source="ShadowOverlay" Grid.RowSpan="2"  Aspect="Fill" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Fill" />

<Grid Margin="10" RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="10" Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="AUTO"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Text="{Binding Title}"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Style="{StaticResource TitleLabel}" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"/>

    <controls:CircleImage Source="{Binding ProfileImage}" Aspect="AspectFill" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" WidthRequest="25" HeightRequest="25" />
    <Label Text="{Binding Handle}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center" Style="{StaticResource HandleLabel}" />

    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Spacing="5">
        <Image Source="Eye"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding ViewCount, StringFormat='{0:N0}'}" Style="{StaticResource HandleLabel}" />
        <Label Text="views" Style="{StaticResource BodyLabel}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

You can see the `Image` on the top (you can disregard the shadow one), and then another grid to make up the rest. The result looks like this:

[image: Result example XAML]

Overlapping icons and text over an image. This should be easily replaceable by a map and other controls.